# How do I get an AJAX callback function to render a Django url or html template with parameters?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am a beginner and working on an app where I want to redirect the user to a checkout-basket
(Django url via POST? Or render html template with variables?) after checking if anything is 
saved in `localStorage`. So I check that and use AJAX to send that data to my Django url
in order to render that template passing on the variables in localStorage as JSON.

But `return render(request, "pizza/prebasket.html", context)` in `views.py` doesn't
work: even though the data is recieved, `prebasket.html` is not rendered.
I read that that's because AJAX doesn't allow that and instead I need to
post through AJAX's callback function. But how do I do that via `POST` and how do I 
pass on the parameters to my view or directly to my html template? 
(`window.location.href` only handles `GET` requests, so I guess that doesn't work).

Here's my JavaScript and my `views.py`:

```
function previous_selection () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("preselection") != null) {

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("preselection", preselection);
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/prebasket');
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    console.log("DATA IS: ", data);
    request.send(data);
    console.log("PRESELECTION IS: ", preselection);

    request.onload = () => {

      // HOW DO I CALL MY URL WITH PARAMETERS HERE?

    };
    return false;
  }
}

previous_selection();
```

In `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def prebasket(request):
  q_preseletion = request.POST.dict()
  preselection = json.loads(q_preselection["preselection"])

  items = []
  # logic iterates thru items to provide 'context'

  context = {"items": items}

  if request.is_ajax():
    html = render_to_string('pizza/prebasket.html', {'items': items})
    return HttpResponse(html)
  return render(request, "pizza/prebasket.html", context)
```

Comment: Hi Anna. I am unclear why you are doing this via AJAX if you want to move to a different page. Or do you want to stay on the same page and some how use the returned HTML?

Comment: Hi @MattEllen - yes, I guess AJAX is primarily (exclusively?) used for getting server info without having to reload the page. That's probably my mistake, because all I want is a) check localStorage client-side b) if it exists, send that info to Django view and render page with that info. Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Is it important that the `preselection` is sent back to the server? You could avoid the AJAX call and build the page in javascript. Otherwise, you'll need to update an element on your page with the relevant details from the AJAX call.

Comment: @MattEllen "Is it important that the ```preselection``` is sent back to the server?" -> I could indeed build the page in JS, but I feel like it would be duplication because it is also an html template on the server that is rendered after selecting menu items. "Otherwise..." -> when the user goes to the ```/``` url or logs in, I am not yet on any page and want JS to check ```localStorage``` to then decide whether to render the menu page or the basket page with the previously selected items (```localStorage```)

Comment: Also, building HTML in JS seems onerous if I depend on CSS and template inheritance that I have on the server...

Comment: You could make the decision of which page to render on the server. If the user has items in their [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) (on the server, not sessionStorage) then load the basket, otherwise show the menu.

Comment: The problem with Django sessions is that once you log out, you lose that session data. I may though have found a way, will post as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take the content of the page returned by your AJAX call to `prebasket`, you can create a fake HTML document and put the returned HMTL into that, then grab the element you need and put that into a container on the current page.

I'm not sure how widely `onload` is supported, so on the safe side this is a callback to `onreadystatechange`:

```
request.onreadystatechange = () => {

  if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
    let status = request.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
      const basket = document.getElementById('basketContainer');
      let parser = new DOMParser();
      const fakePage = parser.parseFromString(request.responseText, "text/html")
      const frm = fakePage.getElementById('basket');
      basket.appendChild(frm);
    }
  }

};
```

This assume your page you're making the AJAX call from has a space or the basket, like

```
<div id="basketcontainer">
</div>
```

Then you'd need to add the CSS relevant to the basket into the same page. You might want to conditionally `display:none` the basket container, in case it messes with the shape of your page.

Comment: thank you - that would get my original approach done. As an update: as you hinted to earlier, it wasn't good design in the first place. I now keep the ```localStorage``` where it is until AFTER I have loaded the 'blank' ```prebasket.html``` page and THEN load the ```localStorage``` content onto it.

Comment: Great to hear :D glad you sorted it out.